# Should a survey page contain a footer?

Tags: footers

We are working on a questionnaire website. The pages consist of a landing page, questionnaire information, the questionnaire, summarised results and a contact information page. All of these currently include a footer, containing mostly legally important information, e.g.:

- a privacy policy,
- a link to contact us for information,
- a copyright text.

Are these necessary on every page? During the questionnaire, I could imagine that showing this information could even be distracting the user from filling in our questionnaire. However, not showing these could lead to distrust.

My current, suggested implementation is: show the footer on every page, but take out as much elements as possible. In this case, I would only keep the copyright text.

Any ideas?

Comment: Website footers are there to contain information or links that *should be available on every page*.

I don't think removing the footer is the answer in this case - I suggest launching the questionnaire in a modal box. This will obscure and disable the page in the background until the questionnaire is either closed or completed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can show a minimal version. Removing the footer altogether is less recommended, as you will remove the natural 'end' of a page. Users may start questioning whether the page loaded correctly, or if content is missing.

Generally, if your user has started a process you want to streamline them through this with as little distractions as possible. Flows like, ordering, filling in forms or anything else that requires focus, can benefit from a minimalist footer. Items to keep are things like the logo, terms of service, certificates and copyright. Essentially, items that build trust, yet do not distract from the main objective.

Here's an example of Bol.com, a well known e-commerce site in the Netherlands.

[image: Footer shown on non-flow pages]

Once you have started the ordering process, you will be greeted with this version:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To be honest I'm not completely sure about what you are asking. However I imagine you will get an answer shortly, if not, check the competition, are they doing it? What about surveyors?

On a separate note, here is an article that could help you optimize your footer if you need to have it obligatorily. I quote from the article:

> In fact, some brands have experienced a 50 percent increase in conversions after optimizing their website footer design

Have a look if it helps you a bit. 
 
 https://uxplanet.org/is-your-footer-at-an-optimal-user-experience-level-cccb6f388614

Comment: Hi Philip, welcome UXSE. A quick point about your answer. Your first sentence suggests you perhaps should have used the comments section under the main question to ask clarifying questions. Good answers contain links, quotes, relevant images, mockups, etc. Before committing the time to provide good answers, it may be in your best interest to be completely sure you know what the question is.

Comment: Hello, as I am a new user I can't comment as I need 50 reputation to do so, but thank you

Comment: Ah, yes, forgot about that. Fair enough.